Electrons repel each other forever - why?
I.e. charge is conserved.
How? Why?


Background
I am coming here with only my intuition, and a desire to learn. My intuition "feels" that if an electron keeps on repelling other electrons, eventually it will lose its ability to do that. Maybe my intuition comes from the fact that there is entropy. That nature isn't "perfect", or "ideal". That this involves forces, and energy, which are things that generally have to "come from somewhere", "get spent", "run out" or "decay". It feels like an activity or an action, and generally activities and actions affect the essence of the actor, in my intuition! Here, they do not.
The combination of all these things and more leads me to surprise when I find out that electrons truly do conserve their charge eternally. I am very interested in getting a better intuition on this, if someone would be able to "explain" it to me (some maths and formulae are welcome, even undergraduate level, but ideally a prose and intuitive explanation if possible).
Many thanks and apologies if this is a stupid question. More background as to why I am asking in this chat.

I'd suggest starting at this video on You Tube: Quantum Electrodynamics - Fermilab video.  No math involved and links to other Fermilab vidoes to go deeper if you want.

Does your intuition tell you that the gravitational attraction between the Sun and the Earth should run out?

@Ghoster reminder, intuition is not the same as instinct, and can be formed from learning. Also, yes, it's exactly the same (or worse, because it radiates grav waves)

The fact that the Earth-Sun system continuously radiates about 200 watts of gravitational waves doesn’t reduce the strength of the gravitational attraction between the two bodies.

@Ghoster I don't think you are understanding my issue. Also, if it's your habit to try to make curious questioners feel dumb, please don't become a teacher

Whatever you’ve learned, you seem to be applying it in areas where it doesn’t apply. In mainstream physics, gravitational attraction doesn’t run out and electrostatic attraction or repulsion doesn’t run out.

When I taught physics, my student evaluations were uniformly excellent. I’m not trying to make you feel dumb. I am pointing out an analogous situation. If you don’t find it useful, ignore my comment. If you find it offensive, flag it.

Electric charges of the identical type have fields that cannot penetrate each other. Comparable with the elastic mutual displacement of two rubber bodies. The two fields cannot dock together. That is their „eternally“ nature. The fields of opposite-pole electric charges, on the other hand, can dock together.  When photons are emitted, the charges shorten their fields with each other.
On the other hand, there are more exotic states. In neutron stars there are neither electrons nor protons, everything is fused into neutrons.

@HolgerFiedler thanks for understanding my question. If you wouldn't mind editing it and submitting to reopen, I would love an answer from you

Your question is fine and there is no need to change anything. It will take more than my single vote to reopen it.

The reason you might feel that electrons should 'lose' their ability affect other electrons might be because the entropy of the universe is increasing which means the amount of 'useless' energy of the universe is increasing. But the electrostatic force is modelled on the charge and separation of the individual charges which doesn't need to account for the entropy.
The electrostatic force simply depends on charges magnitude and the distance between them. An electron cannot lose its ability to affect other electron via force in a normal sense. If two electrons are at some distance from each other, they have stronger repulsion. With this repulsion they seem to affect each other with a smaller force (or a lesser ability). But keep in mind that it is not the loss of ability. It's just the effect of increased separation. They will regain the strength of the force if they are brought back to the original separation. This will be true for any pair of electrons in the entire universe (assuming we do not change the medium).
Charge is an invariant quantity. It doesn't change for an electron under any situations. The magnitude of force surely decrease but that will not be called a loss of ability to affect because the range of electrostatic force is from 0 to infinity. You are right to say that the actor must be affected because the simple Newton's third law states exactly that.

Thanks, glad you got your answer in before it closed. I think that's helped to some degree. Feel free to edit in some equations and experiments that might help deepen my understanding, but don't worry - I am nothing but grateful for your generous time and effort so far either way!

There's really not much to explain here. The conservation of electric charge is consistent with every experiment which has ever been performed, and so it is built in to essentially all of our models (for a recent test, see this open-access summary, or the full paper on the arxiv). It is possible to construct a model which does not have this feature, but if you do so, then you will find that it does not accurately predict the results of experiments.
There's really no deeper explanation required than that your intuition is simply wrong. You don't need to go all the way down to electrons or quantum mechanics to encounter this. Does your intuition also say that it requires a continuous input of energy to hold a box suspended over the floor? Because that is also not true, as you would learn in physics 101.
There's nothing wrong with having incorrect intuition. Your intuition was not developed for doing physics, it was developed for climbing trees and opening nuts with rocks and all of the other survival-related activities our ancestors engaged in. The reason you might expect that holding a box above the floor requires energy is because the human musculoskeletal system works via microscopic contractions and extensions of muscle fibers, and it is this inefficiency which necessitates energy while holding a box. The reason you might expect an electron to eventually lose its charge is because if you charge up a balloon (e.g. by rubbing it on your hair), then the electrons which are "stuck" to the surface of the balloon eventually wander away, and therefore the balloon loses its charge. Bad intuition is usually born from genuine experience.
So the goal is not to explain why the world doesn't fit your intuition - it is to explain why your intuition doesn't fit the world. If charged particles gradually lost their charge, then atoms would fly apart, molecules wouldn't exist, and chemistry would not be possible. Given that we are all still here some ~ 14 billion years after atoms first started to form, it would seem that this doesn't happen, at least not in the most naive picture. If you can come up with a model of charge non-conservation which is consistent with experiment while differing from current theories in measurable ways, then I would be interested to see it.

Sorry but my intuition here is not based on my instincts, but my general physics learning. If the answer is simply "that's what we found by experiment, so therefore assume in our equations" then that's fine, but I am wondering if there's a deeper explanation of why (something similar to what made physicsts theorize that protons decay, even though it's not being observed). "It's the norm, and entropy is the thing that needs explanation" is also fair, but again, I feel more could be said. Maybe I am wrong. I will await further answers but a sincere thank you for taking the time +1

Proton decay is a phenomenon that is possible theoretically but the likelihood is so low that we would have to wait way longer than the probable lifetime of the universe to really observe it happen. Charge conservation is a fact as J. Murray states.  It is not probable but only verifiable by experiments.

@Proscionexium you mean treated as a fact? If not, can you tell me which experiments have proven it? How they proved it?

@RabbiKaii I am not sure about the exact experiments, but I know in general. At first it is estimated what would happen if the charges are in excess and not conserved. But after the experiment, we don't get what we estimated by assumption of non-conservation. So we conclude that charge is always conserved.

@RabbiKaii There is no deeper explanation in empirical science than "that's what we found by experiment." One could say, for example, that in quantum electrodynamics, the electron charge is (essentially) the constant which defines the strength of the coupling between the electron field and the electromagnetic field, and that in order to have a Lorentz invariant theory, that coupling cannot evolve with time. But this is in some sense backwards, because we built quantum electrodynamics by marrying quantum field theory to the Maxwell equations, and the latter already [...]

[...] feature charge conservation as a consequence. If you keep asking why, you will eventually reach "because that's what our experiments tell us" and there simply is nothing more fundamental than that.

@RabbiKaii I have edited this paper into my answer, but here is a recent experiment. The radioactive decay of an electron into a photon and a neutrino would be perfectly consistent with our understanding of quantum mechanics, except for the fact that it violates charge conservation. This experiment demonstrates that if such a decay actually happens, the characteristic time scale is at least a million billion times the age of the observable universe.

Full paper on the Arxiv
